# Wordpress Custom Hook with Class method

Tags: plugins, php, functions, hooks, oop

The code described below works normally outside of wordpress, but in wordpress I get "warning expects parameter 1 to be valid callback function mycars ($ mycarsclass) not found". If I remove $ mycarsclass and leave only add_node, it works normally. How do I enable this for mycars ($ mycarsclass) to be valid? Is this possible in wordpress?

```
<?php
class mycarsclass {
  public $car1;
  public $car2;
function add_node($args) {
    echo '<div class="demo">I lake ' . $args['car1'] . 'and' . $args['car2'] . '</div>';
}
}
$mycarsclass = new mycarsclass();

function mycars($mycarsclass){
     //$mycarsclass = new mycarsclass(); If I add directly to the function it works normally, if the output does not work
    $args = array(
    'car1' => 'Volvo',  
    'car2' => 'Toyota'
    ); 
    
    $mycarsclass->add_node($args);  
}

add_action('mycarsaction','mycars($mycarsclass)'); // 'mycars' It must be without ($mycarsclass) if $mycarsclass = new mycarsclass (); in function mycars
do_action('mycarsaction');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an anonymous function with PHP's `use` statement like so:

```php
function mycars($mycarsclass){
     
    $args = array(
    'car1' => 'Volvo',  
    'car2' => 'Toyota'
    ); 
    
    $mycarsclass->add_node($args);  
}

add_action('mycarsaction', function () use ($mycarsclass) {
    mycars($mycarsclass);
});
do_action('mycarsaction');
```

or declare a separate function and pass that:

```php
function mycars($mycarsclass){
     
    $args = array(
        'car1' => 'Volvo',  
        'car2' => 'Toyota'
    ); 
    
    $mycarsclass->add_node($args);  
}

function mycars_mycarsclass() {
    $mycarsclass = new mycarsclass();
    mycars($mycarsclass);
}

add_action('mycarsaction', 'mycars_mycarsclass');
do_action('mycarsaction');
```

Comment: Petar, Is this possible without any code changes in: `add_action`, `do action` and `function mycars`. Something outside that will call `$mycarsclass` not only in the `mycars function`, but also in other added functions such as `mytrucks function`?

Comment: As far as I know - this can't be done without modifying the `add_action` call. You can either use the above example, or pass a function to `add_action`, that basically calls the `mycars` function and passes the `$mycarsclass` instance.

Comment: In Wordpress this is possible .., eg wordpress code adding toolbar .... For example in the link:   [link](https://www.sitepoint.com/customize-wordpress-toolbar/)

Comment: Petar, can you write edit code, the second part of the example "or pass a function to add_action", to see what you mean?

Comment: deki0 - I edited my answer with what I meant.

Comment: I understand, the problem is that the `function mycars($mycarsclass)`, `add_action` and `do_action` should stay the same. I was looking for tutorials, others are adding new actions and functions to the class `mycarsclass class`, I'm trying but I can't succeed...

Comment: I just noticed that you provided an example with wp admin bar. The thing is, that the do_action there actually passes the instance of the class to the functions you'll hook with `add_action`. It's also a different function used to pass the reference. See [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_bar_menu/).

Comment: They recommend moving this discussion to chat due to extended discussions. I am a new member of the community and I do not have that permission. Peter I noticed that if `$mycarsclass = new mycarsclass ();`  put in the `function mycars ($mycarsclass)` everything works normally. I think for some reason function `mycars ($mycarsclass)` can't take the `$mycarsclass` variable if it's out of function. Otherwise this code works normally outside of wordpress I tested. I edited the code above and added a comment.